# Awaiting an asyncio.Future raises concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError instead of waiting for a value/exception to be set

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, python-3.7

When I run the following python code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

async def read_future(fut):
    print(await fut)

async def write_future(fut):
    fut.set_result('My Value')

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    fut = loop.create_future()
    asyncio.gather(read_future(fut), write_future(fut))

asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

Instead of `read_future` waiting for the result of `fut` to be set, the program crashes with the following error:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: KqueueSelector
ERROR:asyncio:_GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=CancelledError() created at /Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py:642>
source_traceback: Object created at (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 566, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 534, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1763, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in main
  File "/Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 766, in gather
    outer = _GatheringFuture(children, loop=loop)
  File "/Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 642, in __init__
    super().__init__(loop=loop)
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
DEBUG:asyncio:Close <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=True>
```

What am I doing wrong in this code? I want to be able to await the Future `fut` and continue after the Future has a value/exception set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that [`asyncio.gather` is itself async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) (returns an awaitable); by not `await`ing it, you never handed control back to the event loop, nor did you store the awaitable, so it was immediately cleaned up, implicitly cancelling it, and by extension, all of the awaitables it controlled.

To fix, just make sure you `await` the results of the `gather`:

```
await asyncio.gather(read_future(fut), write_future(fut))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@7DsIwDEX3fEU2Ugl1YUPqwkNMbMBaheIGSyGpUoeqX19c2vLM4sQ39/q4aunq3aLr8Fb5QFLXrSvQi/FpvTHojBhretY1FmvvSjTKwh1sNimb7eq4S4R4BsgLlDKAvuRlpBhAcUmWQvKpAjpSutFIsu9@OpqABP8WvqU1UB6gjpbUbN/Kk7YRZl/mm0anRof1vpLZtExqenN0jjnzXlLJlMuf@kZaMOx79CAPjK8MTVcI6nep@T/0RMUmHqoGrjkznqPJDiFC0nUP)

Answer (score -1):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.result:

> `result()`
>
> Return the result of the Future.
>
> If the Future is *done* and has a result set by the `set_result()` method, the result value is returned.
>
> If the Future is *done* and has an exception set by the `set_exception()` method, this method raises the exception.
>
> **If the Future has been *cancelled*, this method raises a `CancelledError` exception.**
>
> If the Future’s result isn’t yet available, this method raises a `InvalidStateError` exception.

<sup>(Bold added.)</sup>

I'm not sure why the `Future` is getting cancelled, but that seems to be the cause of the issue.